# "Cannot find one or more components." when trying to start SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Getting the vague "Cannot find one or more components." message when trying to start SSMS. SSMS used to work before installing the latest VS.

The version of SSMS I'm using is the newest 18.1, I have VS 2019, and have NO OTHER Visual Studio.

There's NO Visual Studio Isolated Shell 2019 (or 2017 for that matter) and installing 2015 DOES NOT solve the issue!!

I'm slightly miffed right now at this pathetic problem. Whoever designed this mess should be fired. Why not give EXACTLY the reason this problem exists in a concise easy to understand error.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled every C++ redistributable package and the 2015 powershell about a billion times (I've also removed all the SQL Management Studio registry keys and uninstalled/reinstalled it too) and this error will NOT go away.

Anyone else have this issue? Any thoughts on solving this?

Comment: Try installing SSMS 17.9.1 (it installs side-by-side). I've found 18.x to be too buggy for me to work with, but 17.9.1 works fairly well for me. Sorry, I don't have any other suggestion.

Comment: 2015 isolated shell work for that?